# r cat command generate output with /t interpreted as /t not tab

Tags: r, tabs, cat, sink

I want to use the following commands to generate an output like "I want to test\ttab", but the output is "I want to test   tab". I want \t to be there rather than being interpreted as a tab delimiter.
Is there a way to do this? Can anyone help? Thank you very much in advance!

```
sink(paste("test","sh",sep="."))
cat(paste0("I want to test","\t","tab"))
cat("\n")
sink()
```

Thanks,
R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add simply an extra slash to escape the following special character:

```
cat(paste0("I want to test","\\t","tab"))
cat("\n")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That helps!

Comment: I am glad. If it answered your question, please check it as the right answer.